# Bootstrap preloader on tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, preloader

I am using some partial views and ajax call to load next tab, the problem sometimes partial has a lot of content thats has to be done on server side, what i need is some got solution that will show preloader inside that element before all data is collected.

Here is simple example of bootstrap tabs, can someone help me to add some preloader, but just inside that place, not on entire page. It wolud be nice to be some CSS preloader

Here is my working fiddle, i removed server side code, for better understanding

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2548/

```
 <div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
            <p>green green green green green</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know in Jquery UI tabs has spinner options, does bootstrap have that also?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery i use this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview and then setup a loading gif image to be set in the blocking html. my example is like

```
$(element).block({ message: '<h5><img src="/images/loader.gif" style="margin-right: 5px;" />loading...</h5>" });
```

this site can create an image for you to download and use. http://www.ajaxload.info/   this allows you to specify exact area to show loading image

Comment: ok check your fiddle code example working you will need to tweak to make work in your project though http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2557/

Answer (score 0):

You can listen `shown.bs.tab` event and add/removeClass `loading` class. You can customize this tab with `loading` class the way you need.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

    var $target = $($(e.target).attr('href'));
    $target.addClass('loading');

    // example of async content loading
    setTimeout(function() {
        $target.html(data[$target[0].id]);

        // once data is loaded remove class
        $target.removeClass('loading');
    }, 1000);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2550/

Comment: The problem loading alwasy stays:(

Comment: When data is loaded you should remove `loading` class of course. See the demo.

Comment: But this is elegant solution when i know how many tabs i have, i dont need that, because i dont know how many tabs i will have, and i dont want to control that JS also :(

Comment: You don't have to know how many tabs you have at all. This is pretty generic solution.

Comment: The probem is here 
var data = {
    orange: '<h1>Orange</h1><p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>',
    yellow: '<h1>Yellow</h1><p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>',
    green:  '<h1>Green</h1><p>green green green green green</p>',
    blue:   '<h1>Blue</h1><p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>'
};

Comment: You said that you have AJAX requests, right? In my demo I don't have requests, but this is not important part od the solution. I used setTimeout and `data` variable just to illustrate how data comes dynamically. In your case you have AJAX request.

Comment: My logic if diferrent, i have some wizard that have NEXT and BACK